# \Mapsto in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, tikz-cd

I'm loving using tikz-cd to draw compiler correctness diagrams, but I can't manage to get quite the same arrows for relations that I'm using in the text. In particular, I'm not sure how to get `\Mapsto` in a tikz-cd diagram.

I did try combining arrow options to get `\Mapsto` to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  M \rar[Rightarrow] \dar[maps to] & N \dar[maps to, Rightarrow] \\
  M' \rar[Rightarrow, maps to] & N'
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

But this wound up less than satisfactory (on TeXLive 2013):

[image: Garbled arrows]

As you can see, depending on the order I give the arguments, the bar is either missing (there should be one on the N-to-N' arrow) or comically huge. I assume this is a bug? Any known workaround?

Comment: `tikz-cd` doesn’t provide a `maps to` arrow for a doubled line, the arrows `|` and `cm |` (which is internally used here) does use the “doubled” line width and not the simple one. Looks like you need either to correct the arrow code for `cm |`/|` or introduce a new arrow.

Comment: Well, according to the tikz-cd manual, the arrows with alternate names (one of which is `mapsto`/`maps to`) “can be superimposed with other arrows.” If it's not intended that I can mix the maps to and Rightarrow options, I think that's a documentation bug at any rate.

In any case, I guess I'm shy about diving into arrow code and hoping there's a simpler way. Also IIUC there's an impedance mismatch between tikz-cd arrows, which combine the specification of the path with that of the arrow tip (I guess this is the source of the maybe-bug?), and tikz arrows (really just tips?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve taken a look at the `\Mapsto` arrow from the [`stmaryrd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) package which I have used as the model for the redefinition of the `cm |` arrow that obeys a `double` line.

The `3.3` value is approximated so that the vertical line is as wide as the `implies` arrow (similar to how `\Mapsto` looks). The original `maps to` arrow as seen in the example has a rather short bar.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\expandafter\let\csname pgf@arrow@code@cm |\endcsname\relax
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{cm |}{cm |}{%
  \pgfutil@tempdima.5\pgflinewidth
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt\relax
    \pgfmathaddtolength\pgfutil@tempdima{-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \fi
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}%
}{%
  \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth=0pt\relax
    \pgfutil@tempdima4\pgflinewidth
  \else
    \pgfutil@tempdima\pgflinewidth
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima-\pgfinnerlinewidth
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfutil@tempdima/2}%
    \multiply\pgfutil@tempdima3.3\relax
  \fi
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother
\pgfqkeys{/tikz/commutative diagrams}{
  Maps to/.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/Rightarrow,
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/maps to},
  Maps from/.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/Leftarrow,
    /utils/exec=\pgfsetarrowsend{cm |}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  M  \rar[Maps from] \dar[maps to]  & N \dar[Maps to] \\
  M' \rar[Maps to]    & N'
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks! It's probably a bit much to ask that I be able to understand the code fully :-) but I take it the crux is checking `\pgfinnerlinewidth`, which will be zero for a single arrow (line) but positive for a double?

Comment: @LukeMaurer Oh, me stupid. I have used `\ifx` where I should have used `\ifdim` to compare dimens. With the updated code, the single line `maps to` bar is the same as before (still a little shorter in comparison with the doubled one but well …).

Comment: This doesn't work as of tikz 3.0.1a, but (see my new answer) there's a much easier solution: tikz-cd 0.9 has `Mapsto` built in.

Answer (score 6):

As of version 0.9c (if not earlier), tikz-cd now provides a `Mapsto` arrow.